# lookupDefaultPrintService() doesn't return system default printer

Tags: java, printing

**Configuration:**

- **OS:** CentOS release 5.4
- **Linux:** 2.6.18-164.el5
- **Java:** 1.7.0_25

Hi,

I'm having a hard time figuring out why the print dialog in my Java application uses the wrong printer as default.

`lpstat -d` returns 'printer_ip0', and the `printenv` command doesn't return the LPDEST or PRINTER variables (which, in my understanding, take precedence over the system default setting).

Yet, every time I start a print job, the first printer in alphabetical order (printer1) is shown first, and `PrintServiceLookup.lookupDefaultPrintService().getName()` gives the same result.

**EDIT:**

When enabling IPP debugging (`System.setProperty("sun.print.ippdebug", "true")`), I get the following logs:

```
CUPSPrinter>> libfound false
UnixPrintServiceLookup>> total# of printers = 2
CUPSPrinter>> libfound false
CUPSPrinter>> libfound false
CUPSPrinter>> libfound false
isRunning ? false
CUPSPrinter>> libfound false
```

This lead me to the class `CUPSPrinter()` in the sun.print package, and in particular:

```
static {
   // load awt library to access native code
   java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(
   new sun.security.action.LoadLibraryAction("awt"));
   libFound = initIDs();
   if (libFound) {
       cupsServer = getCupsServer();
       cupsPort = getCupsPort();
   }
}
```

Unfortunately, it still doesn't tell me why it cannot access the native code.

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't know exactly what solved my issue, but after a `yum update` it was gone!